# Is there a shortcut to destructure an object properties while keeping the object?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

if I have a method signature as follows:

```
const myFunction = ({ property1, property2, property3 }) => ...
```

Is there a way I can also grab the parent object? Otherwise I have to write this:

```
const myFunction = myObject => {
   const { property1, property2, property3 } = myObject
}
```

Comment: would `arguments[0]` work?

Comment: At some point you gotta ask: how much shorter can it get? Why not `o => { o.propery1 ... }`?

Comment: @OliverRadini - Oh, ick. And...wow, if he used a traditional (non-arrow) function, yes, it would: http://jsfiddle.net/6xybnpuh/ So...that's an answer, then. Suggesting posting it as an answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for confirming that; can't say I've ever used it myself, doesn't seem like the friendliest pattern

Comment: @OliverRadini - :-) Yeah. Still, the question is "can you," and yours is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks all, I'd seen this on twitter somewhere and lost it. Now found -> https://twitter.com/RyanWillDev/status/1027628197733646337

Comment: I was definitely after a way of doing this inside the destructuring syntax btw, sorry if that wasn't clear from the title & body!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example below you can access the `x` & `y` properties and `cords` itself, through destructuring:

```js
const drawCircle = ({cords, cords: {x,y},radius}) =>
  console.log(cords, x, y, radius)

const circle = {
  cords: {
    x: 18,
    y: 30
  },
  radius: 50
}

drawCircle(circle)
```

It's a bit unwieldy but you can get the entire object, by calling the function with:

`drawCircle({circle})`

and destructuring the object like so:

`({circle, circle: {cords, cords: {x, y}, radius}})`

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use a traditional function as opposed to an arrow function, you can use the `arguments` object to get this:

```js
function test({a, b}) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(arguments[0]);
}

test({
  a: 'This is a',
  b: 'This is b',
});
```

(You can't do that in an arrow function because arrow functions don't have their own `arguments` binding, they close over the one in their surrounding context, like they do `this` and [where relevant] `super`.)

Comment: conradj - You *can* do this (nice one, Oliver!), but with respect, you probably shouldn't. If you're going to be using other parts of the object, just declare those in the destructuring pattern. If you need the object reference itself, just use your final code block's pattern. That way, you're correctly indicating your intent. Using `arguments[0]` means your function signature misleads the reader regarding your intent.